# How do i improve this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following piece of PHP code for matching a birth year:

```
$pattern = "/20\d\d/";

$exp = "BORN ON:        Friday, June 11, 2001 ";

$match = preg_match($pattern,$exp, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

This matches `"2001"`...which is what I am trying to match--the birth year. But this is clearly a hack of a solution and can run into problems if there are other years before `$exp` for some reason.
How can I include the `"BORN ON"` information to pick out just the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search also for "BORN ON" and use a capturing group.

```
$pattern = "/BORN ON.*(20\d\d)\s$/";
$exp = "BORN ON:        Friday, June 11, 2001 ";
$match = preg_match($pattern,$exp, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

I put the Year into a capturing group because of the brackets around it now, you get this group with the `$matches[1]` (instead of 0). Additionally I bound the year to the end of the string (there can be whitespace `\s` in between) with the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'/BORN ON:\s+\w+, \w+ \d+, (20\d\d)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "BORN ON.*/20\d\d/";
```

It is sometimes helpful to develop regular expressions from an example using to tool like http://txt2re.com .  It can give you the exact PHP code to use to match the string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, normalize all of the input data. If the string you're parsing is fixed-width or follows a specific, simple format then note that and develop a regex that will better suit the  input data. If you need a quick reference, check out [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/).